# Unable to upload file to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I've tried a few different approaches but so far the same result, which is the post request appears to contain no files.

The latest example I tried is here: https://www.codingwithcalvin.net/uploading-files-with-httpclient-in-net-6/

My controller looks like this (from this example)

[image]

However at the break-point, the file file is always zero length.

For the client I've tried a few different examples with the same result, the latest being this jQuery one:
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

The jQuery one seems to work quite well and the request looks good in Chrome dev tools, but in the controller action the file list is still empty.

[image]

Is there some config or something I should have added to the controller to allow this to happen?

This is the HTML client (someone's bound to ask) - not much to see as it uses the jQuery upload script, but thought I'd include it.
[image: jQuery file upload element]

This form has exactly the same result:
[image: Basic file upload form]

Comment: You don't show all code related to client side, but in the ASP.NET Core MVC you can just use `<form asp-action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" />...`. Especially important the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` parameter in this case.

Comment: Yep I just added a conventional HTML form that I've tried, but I'll try that also. Thanks.

Comment: That worked. I think the `name` attribute was key. Obvious when you know! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, key of the problem is `name` attribute: `<input type="file" name="file">`. It should be specified to be able the MVC binding to work properly.

But when I tried to test this code fragment on clean project created from the ASP.NET Core MVC template (.NET 6) I got the `404 Not Found` error. I don't see any routing rules, except in the screen shot. Only way to start it work was adding `controller` segment to the `Route` attribute:

```
[HttpPost("/{controller}/upload-file")]
public IActionResult Uploadfile(IFormFile file)
{
    //var routes = HttpContext.Request.RouteValues;            
    ...
}
```